# Should I update my peer dependencies while upgrading RN version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I tried upgrading one of my legacy projects from RN 0.61.x to 0.70.x, react 16 to react 18 recently.
I noticed that there were a lot of dependencies which relied on older RN version in their peer dependencies.
This throws an error in npm 8. I found this https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/ and they say we can use

> You have the option to retry with --force to bypass the conflict or --legacy-peer-deps command to ignore peer dependencies entirely (this behavior is similar to versions 4-6)
> I am confused as to which route to take solve for the peer dependency issues also or just ignore them.
> Which approach should I use and why?

So far I have moved many dependencies to use the new react version but some of these dependencies depend on other dependencies which use old react versions as their peers.

Some are internal libraries I maintain and others are external ones.

Answer (score 0):

This site might help you to upgrade between certain react native versions:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

But I think you will find other issues related to your own case. Better create new react native project with latest version and move your files manually from old to new project. Also install your libraries one by one to test if it breaks or not.

Comment: Hey I saw that but my question is specific to peer- dependencies.